# how can i refresh automaticly View page on MVC4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm building a web page using MVC. I want to refresh my entire view every 30 seconds
i know about  
but I'm looking for somthing more elegant.

I have a regular Controller and regular View like this:

Controller:
   HomeController

View:
   Index

Comment: Use JavaScript or AJAX. Use a the meta refresh tag.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [**meta-tags**](http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/meta.http-equiv.refresh.html)

```
 <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="30" >
```

Where `30` is in seconds

**OR**

If you wish you can use simple JavaScript

```
setTimeout(function(){
    window.location.reload(true);
}, 30000);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to refresh the whole page, Use meta tag `<meta http-equiv="refresh"` in your header/

```
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5" />
</head>
<body>
    ...
</body>
```

or you could try to add a response header in your controller action:

```
public Result Index()
{
    Response.AddHeader("Refresh", "5");
    return View();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could reset a form from the javascript code:

```
this.form.reset();
```

After setting a timer on it. 
Though in the majority of cases there is no need to refresh the whole view - please think whether you really need to refresh the whole view or only certain parts of this (which makes the whole refresh operation more user-friendly and faster).